# WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv

Tags: python-3.x, azure, flask-restful

I have a rest api projet with flask and this is the error when i deploy it to azure
This my project structure:

i have flask_alchemy in requirement.txt but i receive the error.

this is my log

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i solved the problem:
configuration -> App settings -> add new app setting 
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true

Comment: In my case is a Django App, the app setting is there and get the error